# How to edit drop-down selected value?

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have created a drop-down menu and many other text fields on my html page which fetches the option values from database. It is inserting the selected values in my database table. I want to edit the selected values from the drop-down menu and update them in database. When I open the edit page, the form shows the previous saved values to edit them. But the problem is; When I don't edit the drop-down values and submit the form, It shows me error of undefined index and when I edit or select different value of drop-down then it works fine and don't show any error. Here is my code:
**HTML**

```html
<label>Courses</label><select name="courses" id="courses" class="dropdownclass"><option selected="selected" value="" disabled selected hidden>-- Select an option --</option><?php  
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('db');

$sql = "SELECT courses FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 
    echo "<option value=' " . $row['courses'] ."'>" . $row['courses'] ."</option>";
}

?>
  </select>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

**EDITRECORD**

```html
<?php
include("connection.php");
$Sno = (int)$_GET['Sno'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE Sno = '$Sno'") or die(mysql_error());


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

if (isset($_POST)) {
 
echo "";
$id=$row['id'];
$courses=$row['courses'];
}   
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Edit Record</title>
  </head>
<body>
<form id="form" action="update.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="new" id="Sno" value="<?=$Sno;?>" />
        <label>Courses</label><select name="courses" id="courses" class="dropdownclass"  ><option selected="selected" value="" disabled selected hidden><?php echo $courses; ?></option><?php  
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('db');

$sql = "SELECT courses FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 
    echo "<option value=' " . $row['courses'] ."'>" . $row['courses'] ."</option>";
}

?>
  </select> 
    </fieldset>

 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

```html
<?php
 include("connection.php");

    $Sno =''; 
if( isset( $_POST['new'])) {
    $Sno = (int)$_POST['new']; 
}
  $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
  if(isset($_POST['courses'])){
        $courses = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['courses']);
    }else{
        $courses=$_POST['courses'];
    }
    query="UPDATE technicalsol
            SET id= '$id',
            courses = '$courses'
             WHERE Sno=$Sno";
             $res= mysql_query($query);
if($res){
   echo "<div style ='font-size:20px; margin-left:140px;'>Records updated Successfully</div>";
   include("search.php");
    
}else{
    echo "Problem updating record. MY SQL Error: " . mysql_error();
}
?>
```

I want that; If I don't edit the drop-down selected value, It just takes the previous value and saves it.

Comment: the problem you are having is when you do not edit and submit right? This gives you an undefined index error?

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Also, this: `$courses=$_POST['courses'];` doesn't make sense since you're doing it if `$_POST['courses']` _isn't_ set.

Answer (score -1):

What you are doing right now is listing the options in dropdown list.
You are not setting up any answer

In your HTML:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo "<option value=' " . $row['courses'] ."'>" . $row['courses'] ."</option>";
    }
```

make sure you make the old value selected.
may be by using an IF statement

Comment: _"make sure you make the old value selected. may be by using an IF statement"_ - Instead of just copy/pasting the OP's code, you should show the OP how to do it.

Comment: may I know what is that you get in displayed in your generated html option against value and option text fro dropdown?

Comment: I need to know the attributes of $row that are used in for value and text of dropdown. Without that, I will not be able to write code for selection

Comment: Also, I need to know the previous value that was selected

Comment: It fetches these values from database

Comment: The previous value that is selected is just $ courses